# How to install gksu which was removed from distributions?

Tags: gksu, gksudo

We are forced to install ClearPass OnGuard which seems to require `gksu` which was removed from Linux distributions. Is there a way to get it from some 3rd party PPA or other source? Preferably, updated to work well with Ubuntu Disco 19.04.